# Python, double autoenumerated defaultdict

Tags: python, nested, hashmap, defaultdict

To optimize some code, I am using the following:

```
a = defaultdict(lambda: len(a))
a[0] = 0
a[1] = 1
a[7] = 2
...
```

Now my problem is that I would need a nested defaultdict, i.e.

```
b = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: len(b[?]))
b[0][0] = 0
b[0][1] = 1
b[1][0] = 0
b[1][1] = 1
...
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can't do this with `defaultdict` -- you'll need to write your own custom `dict` subclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def enumdict():
    a = defaultdict(lambda : len(a))
    return a

b = defaultdict(enumdict)
```

Comment: How to convert it all to into just one lambda expression?

Comment: It would also be ver constructive to read directly from you the explanation about how this is the minimal way of implementing it

Comment: I don't know if this is the minimal way, and actually I would prefer to create class for this task -- this feels like a trick.

Comment: For this to work, it is important that `a` is a local variable inside a function. You can't assign a variable inside a lambda. Each time enumdict is called, a new lambda function is created, and each lambda refers to a different `a`.

Comment: @JanneKarila, you can, at least in Python 2.x (but not 3.x), this will work, but writing it out as a named function as you did is a million times better: `b = defaultdict(lambda: [a for a in (defaultdict(lambda: len(a)),)][0])`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Janne karila and Duncan

Comment: @Duncan Well you can't do it with non-hacky code is what JanneKarila meant :)

Answer (score 2):

If you ever want to make it a class:

```
class CountDict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self):
        defaultdict.__init__(self, self.default_factory)

    def default_factory(self):
         sub = defaultdict()
         sub.default_factory = sub.__len__
         return sub
```

You can't normally do this in a lambda because you need to assign the child default dict to a variable to be able to get its len afterwards, which is not possible in lambdas. @Duncan came up with a workaround using list comprehension to act like assignment. Good job :) but don't use it.. :D